# Bing Maps JSON not parsing with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, bing-maps, winjs

I'm trying to use Bing Maps for reverse geocoding purposes in a Windows Store Application. My request (using WinJS.xhr) goes through just fine, and I get a response similar to this one from their example page:

```
{
   "authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials",
   "brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
   "copyright":"Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
   "resourceSets":[
      {
         "estimatedTotal":1,
         "resources":[
            {
               "__type":"Location:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
               "bbox":[
                  47.636705672917948,
                  -122.137016420622,
                  47.6444311080593,
                  -122.1217297861384
               ],
               "name":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
               "point":{
                  "type":"Point",
                  "coordinates":[
                     47.640568390488625,
                     -122.1293731033802
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "addressLine":"1 Microsoft Way",
                  "adminDistrict":"WA",
                  "adminDistrict2":"King Co.",
                  "countryRegion":"United States",
                  "formattedAddress":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
                  "locality":"Redmond",
                  "postalCode":"98052"
               },
               "confidence":"Medium",
               "entityType":"Address",
               "geocodePoints":[
                  {
                     "type":"Point",
                     "coordinates":[
                        47.640568390488625,
                        -122.1293731033802
                     ],
                     "calculationMethod":"Interpolation",
                     "usageTypes":[
                        "Display",
                        "Route"
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "matchCodes":[
                  "Good"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "statusCode":200,
   "statusDescription":"OK",
   "traceId":"99b1256e09044490bce82bbbba1dab7a"
}
```

However when I call JSON.parse on the data and try to display it, all it returns is

```
[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're displaying it wrong.

Comment: How are you trying to display it? using alert? or setting it to some DOM element, if so it just stringifies the object's type name. parse converts it into `object`.

Comment: How do you want this to be displayed? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: My bad. I'm using "var locJSON = JSON.parse(result.responseText)" to parse and then trying "$('div.jsonOut').html(locJSON);" to display it in my HTML. That code displays nothing, but when I skip the parsing and just display the response it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it *did* parse, you just don't recognise the result.

`JSON` is a serialisation of an object heirarchy to a string.

`JSON.parse(...)` turns a JSON serialisation (string) back into an object heirarchy.

That heirrarchy of objects can't juse be displayed -- it can be traversed! -- you'll need to encode it into something that *can* be displayed (for example HTML).

To do that, you traverse the object heirarchy building up an HTML fragment string. Then you can simply add that to the HTML DOM via the `innerHTML` propery of an existing element (say a container DIV).

Comment: Well colour me embarrassed, I guess I still don't quite have my head wrapped around JSON. Thank you very much for helping me through my arrogance :P